# Windows Service with timer and limited amount of Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have something to do and I don't know exactly how.

**What's already working:**
I have Windows Service with a System.Timers.Timer which runs every 5 sec.

**What I know how to do:**
This timer should check a directory (No problem) and if there is a file, it should start one Action per file, which executes some stuff, one is to start an application.
First line of this action is to move the file to a temp directory and after this application ended successful I have to delete the file from the temp folder (In general everything no problem)

**What IS the problem:**
I have to limit this Actions to 10 simultaneously.
And if possible I want to use the new Action and Task stuff instead of ThreadPool and Thread.

**So, how do I achieve this?**
I know there is:

```
Parallel.Invoke(new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, actions);
```

But how do I ensure that every File/Action is only processed once?
For example, the timer elapsed event fires, there are 12 files, I add 12 Actions to a List and call this Parallel.Invoke, 10 actions are running, 4 are finished, then again the timer elapsed event is fired 20 new files, again add the 20 to the List, which now contains 28 Actions, and Parallel.Invoke again?!
Then the non finished Actions from the first timer run, are gone a be  executed twice, right?

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: You count with a Semaphore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really a clear and cut question but ill give it my best:

Don't use `Parallel.Invoke` and lose the timer. Have a `Task` (`Task.Run`) with a `while` in it, and use `Task.Delay(5000)` inside it. That ensures you won't reenter the operation if it takes more than you plan it to take.

Inside the while simply check for files and push the "action items" into a TPL Dataflow's ActionBlock that asynchronously takes care of every single file (copying, deleting and so forth).
Make sure you set the MaxDegreeOfParallelism to 10.

This basically creates a "Watcher" that fills a "Pipe" and runs an action on every item in it (which is the file in question)

Comment: Tank you very very much, you don't see that in any Windows Service tutorial, there is ever used a Timer!

Kind regards